# Sails.js application not refreshing files from assets after start

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sails.js

I have a Sails.JS application with Angular.JS front-end.
The angular files are stored in /assets/linker and they are injected properly on start. My issue is that when I change css or js file from assets the change doesn't appear on the server, the loaded js file is the same as when the server started. I tried to clear my browser cache and tried in another browser, but still the same.
I also tried to run the application with `forever -w` and `nodemon`, but still nothing. The application is in dev mode, anyway starting with `sails lift --dev` does not solve the issue neither.

I have feeling that I miss something in configuration. Is there any way to force reloading of assets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to check your Gruntfile configuration. It's where the **magic** happen in term of linker and livereload.

Specifically, you'll need to look at the `watch` task and the related `tasks`.
By default it looks like this :

```
watch: {
  api: {

    // API files to watch:
    files: ['api/**/*']
  },
  assets: {

    // Assets to watch:
    files: ['assets/**/*'],

    // When assets are changed:
    tasks: ['compileAssets', 'linkAssets']
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me to see the root of the problem and the way files are reloaded. The +50 is going to you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I made the Angular.js structure with [angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)
which adds not only the js structure, but also karma test environment containing shell and bat scripts, karma framework and more.

Building sails application with all these files in watched folder is breaking the refresh functionality. There's no errors in console and nothing in the running application, but the files from assets are not reloaded anymore.

Tip of the day: be careful with the files you have in assets and take a look what does generators generate!

Comment: I couldn't agree more, we started a project with the Yeoman Sails-generator. It ended up being a _very bad idea™_ : the sails version is outdated, and there is no easy way to update as the files it generates may break if you try to. Starting over with a simple `sails new <project>` helped getting a clean starting point. I'm glad my answer helped you even though it wasn't dead on.

Comment: I had the same issue when I was using Bower to manage my dependencies. It seems like it might be an issue with Sails having trouble managing a large number of files in the assets directory. It's hard to tell, though, without getting an error message.

Comment: So what would you get out of assets folder safely to reduce the amount of files in there ?

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for livereload, after a little search

[Live Reloading](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/docs/watch-examples.md#live-reloading)

[Enabling Live Reload in Your HTML](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/docs/watch-examples.md#enabling-live-reload-in-your-html)

in current version of Sails v0.10 there is a file for watch task: tasks/config/watch.js