# Server latest assets/views automatically

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I am running SailsJS in production with `forever` and the development has been working great so far.
But coming from a PHP background there seem to be a few things still not working as smoothly in production. One of the biggest pains we had recently, is when you update an asset or a view (in our case an `ejs` file) the server has to be restarted to serve the latest files.

One solution I could use with sails is run a grunt watchtask in production or use forever -w, but both seem a bit unnatural, having to 'watch' for filechanges, rather than just displaying the latest.

Not sure if that is an issue purely with Sails but I would guess this is more of a general problem with Express and Node. So is there any way to have a Sails/Express/Node server always display the newest assets/files/views without having to explicitly watch for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express should render the template on the fly--maybe I'm missing something with the SailsJS setup though.  If that is the case, this question might help: [Sails.js application not refreshing files from assets after start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754397/sails-js-application-not-refreshing-files-from-assets-after-start).

As for the other things in this realm that might not be "working as smoothly":

In a typical setup, possibly unlike you might in PHP, you would deploy the entire site as opposed to just one file.  This is mostly to do with the fact that you are running Node.JS as a stand-alone service, and you want everything that pertains to that instance to be packaged together in each deployment.  Not to mention, you probably don't want to ever have to worry about the incurred overhead with monitoring the file system for changes, so this behavior is most useful in a dev environment.

That means too that if you're serving static files, you should probably setup your web server to serve them from the file system directly, as opposed to letting your node application serve them.  In fact, that alone could reduce your asset download time by a factor of 5 to 10.

A setup that I commonly use for my applications is this: *git* to deploy your application (using the post-receive hook) and *daemontools* to make sure that the service stays up.  This would give you a slick deployment setup similar to Heroku or Nodejitsu.

I believe this is a common setup for production Node.JS systems.  And, after my own research into what was available out there about a year ago, there really wasn't anything that I would consider solid and reliable (including *Forever*) in terms of what years of the *nix community has already accomplished.

*daemontools* is far superior to even a lot of other *nix service managers, but it's not commonly employed because its author, DJB, believes that software shouldn't concern itself with things like being a service.  This is exactly what makes it ideal for Node.JS applications, though a little bit less ideal for a lot of Unix applications that are still built as stand-alone services (though a lot of software can work with daemontools by allowing for a non-daemon mode, not all software will, which means that distributions need to develop their own solutions).

With that, you can't always guarantee that the service won't crash with node, and that those crashes won't pollute the server's resources, even if you're able to "catch" them.  It almost works better to capture exceptions into a log or email, let the service fail, bail, and cleanup, and then have daemontools kick it back off automatically.  You can read more about error handling in Node.JS here: http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html

Comment: SailsJS render the template on the fly as long as you are in development mode. The reason this would be really useful in production, is because we are serving an Ember app through the template and so you would just have to update the app - and not touch the server at all. Which it seems would only work with continuously watching the templates, right?

Thank you for this detailed answer though, I will take a look into daemontools. I just found https://github.com/Unitech/PM2 which looks great feature-wise but is obviously not as stable as daemontools.

Comment: Also you are mentioning serving the static files using a web server. So you would basically run nginx on top of node, and just proxy the requests through?

Comment: That is correct about the Nginx proxy.  You can find an example here: http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-2-using-nginx-to-avoid-node-js-load/.  I played with PM2 a bit and after a lot of frustration, I couldn't get it to work correctly with my deployment.  I liked the features though, it may be worth looking into since it may have come along since then.

Comment: I played around with PM2 and it has some really nice features and it seems like a lot of work has gone into it over the last view months.
To get back to my questions, it seems there is currently no other way to updated templates/views in production then either watching or using PM2's `reload` functionality.
But maybe this http://strongloop.com/strongblog/whats-new-in-node-js-v0-12-execsync-a-synchronous-api-for-child-processes/ is the real answer to my question (apart from the nginx part of course)

Comment: I suppose that is also giving me an answer to my question: http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-3-zero-downtime-deployments-with-nginx/ which if I understand it correctly has a somewhat similar idea to how PM2 does it for you.
Oh and thanks again for your links and answers karma0.